# Does H2Dialect support INNER JOIN <> ON <>?

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I have an entity class with many named queries with INNER JOIN<> ON <> sentence on it, when I try to execute a test using JUnit and in memory H2 database I get this exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

The query work fine, but it seems that H2Dialect dont support Inner Join this way, only like this:

```
INNER JOIN  c.persona p
```

This is my NamedQuery:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "name", query = "SElECT NEW MyObject(p.firstName, "
                + "p.lastName, , tp.otherName, p.id, s.description, en.name, et.name , et.number,  e.firstName, "
                + "e.lastName, e.street, e.date ) "
                + "FROM TypeC c INNER JOIN c.typeP p " + "INNER JOIN TypeTP tp ON tp.code = p.codeTP "
                + "INNER JOIN TypeS s ON s.code   = c.codeS "
                + "INNER JOIN TypeEt et ON et.code   = c.codeET "
                + "INNER JOIN TypeEN en ON en.code = c.codeEN "
                + "INNER JOIN TypeI i ON i.code = c.codeI " + "INNER JOIN i.typeE e "
                + "WHERE c.number = :NUMBER " + "AND e.code = :CODE ")
```

I'm using JPA.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the full HQL or JPQL statement (and explicitly specify if you are using HQL or JPQL). Your statement doesn't seem complete. Consider posting a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that if this is the full statement, then you have a syntax error. It should then be something like `select TypeC c from TypeC c inner join c.persona p` (where `TypeC` is whatever `c` is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found whats went wrong. TypeS, TypeET and TypeEN needed to be included in the persistence.xml file into the tag "persistence-unit" as

```
<class>co.com.myproject.persistence.entity.TypeS </class>
<class>co.com.myproject.persistence.entity.TypeET </class>
<class>co.com.myproject.persistence.entity.TypeEN </class>
```

and put the necesary SQL code for create and populate the tables in the create.sql and data.sql files used to generate the in memory h2 database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try **JOIN** instead **INNER JOIN**, **JOIN** means inner join by default.
2. Change **H2** dialect to another if it possible.

Comment: I already tried your to change INNER JOIN by JOIN but it didn't work either, I will try to change the dialect, any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure that query is right:
Example join account and card:
... JOIN account ON cardAccountID = account.id ...

Comment: The query isn't actually an SQL query, but a (fragment of) HQL (Hibernate Query Language) or JPQL (Java Persistance Query Language) statement which is translated by Hibernate to actual SQL.